# Crontab bash script doesn't work

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I have a simple script and I try to run this every 3: 00 am via crontab.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/screen -SX fbbot quit;
/usr/bin/screen -dmS fbbot /home/vemu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node /home/vemu/fbbot/src/index.js;
```

It just restart the screen session and if I execute it works, but when I place it in `crontab -e` it closes screen, but doesn't start new. Crontab:

```
0 3 * * * /home/vemu/fbbot/restart.sh >> /home/vemu/fbbot/log.txt 2>&1
```

What's wrong?

Comment: When you run `crontab -e` and you don't see any path statements in your crontab file, then you will have to give the full path name to the files.  So, you will probably need to give the full path to the `fbbot` and `node` files.

Comment: @Terrance still not working

Comment: @Vemu please [edit] your question and show the current version of the script that includes the full paths.

Comment: Just a observation, running something in `/usr/bin` requires sudo privileges right?

Comment: Possible missing $DISPLAY environment variable. `screen` needs that.